# UIViewController not added to the view controller hierarchy after performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have the following method which functions properly when the app is in foreground. The SecondViewController gets pushed to the top of the UINavigationController's view controller stack.

I have two UIViewController's FirstViewController and SecondViewController in a UINavigationController and FirstViewController is the rootViewController of the UINavigationController

```
 1. UINavigationController *navigationController =
    (UINavigationController*) self.navigationController;      
 2. [self.navigationController
    performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSecondView" sender:self];     
 3. SecondViewController * secondController = (SecondViewController*)
    navigationController.viewControllers[1];       
 4. [secondController performSomeAction];
```

After pushing the SecondViewController, I pop to UINavigationController's rootViewController which is FirstViewController. This code works fine when the app is in the foreground.

I have an iOS8 interactive notification calling the FirstViewController, which pushes the SecondViewController using performSegueWithIdentifier.

Interactive Notification correctly calls the FirstViewController but the UINavigationController controller does not push the SecondViewController(see above code), even though the code correctly when the app is in the foreground.

**Some Initial Investigations I did**

- Segue Identifier is correct
- When I put the breakpoint on the fourth line on the case where the UINavigationController does not push the SecondViewController, secondController instance is a SecondViewController.
- breakpoint showed that the UINavigationController only had FirstViewController even after the performSegueWithIdentifier.
- No memory leak in instruments

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you tried [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSecondView" sender:self]; instead of self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifer? and are you sure that segue is "push" instead of "modal"?

Comment: yeah I tried self performSegueWithIdentifier too but it did not work :(. Yes the segue is push and works fine when the app is in the foreground.